# Creating a canvas animation that covers the entire viewport without triggering overflow without using position: absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to make an HTML canvas animation that will span the entire viewport that does not cause horizontal overflow, but I do not want to use `position: absolute` because ideally, I would want to just be able to treat it like any other element and retain natural flow in my HTML.

The tricky part about using  is that CSS width and height just scales it without changing the internal width / height. Also, trying to change it with Javascript by using `document.body.clientWidth / clientHeight`, `window.innerWidth / innerHeight`, or `canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width / height` all do not work because they do not account for the vertical scrollbar (for the rest of the page).

By this I mean that on my 1920x1080 monitor, the width will be set to 1920 even though my viewport width is only 1903 (17px from scrollbar), causing horizontal overflow. The strange behavior about this is that when I use devtools to check the width of the canvas's parent element's height, it says 1903. So I would think that saying `set the canvas's width to the parent's width (1903)` would set it to 1903, but it instead sets it to 1920. And, I do not want to just subtract 17 from that width because that is not reliable across all browsers.

See this code for an example:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas class="splash-canvas" />
        <!-- rest of site -->
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.splash-canvas
{
    background-color: #090909;
}
```

```js
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.querySelector(".splash-canvas");

canvas.width = canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
// devTools says body's width is 1903, but this function returns 1920
// since no(?) methods return the viewport size excluding the amount covered by the scrollbar

canvas.height = canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;

// canvas's width and height is now 1920x929 (for me)
```

I think using `position: absolute` might just be necessary here, but I really think there should be a better solution here. Either way, I appreciate any help, thank you!